# wondering why my code didn't work for deleting any number I wanted?

Tags: python

```
f = open('num.txt','r')
temf = open('temp.txt','w')
n = f.readline()
num = input('please enter a number ')
found = False
while n != '':
    if n != num:
        temf.write(str(n))
    else:
        found = True
    n = f.readline()
f.close()
temf.close()

if found:
    print('found,and removed')
else:
    print('no such number')
```

as you see the code above, my num.txt contained 0,1,2...100 and my temp.txt is empty. I've set a Boolean variable as 'found' and an if  condition inside the loop as if the number is existed then its returned True. but when I put the existed number as input and its fail the if condition at the last line and always print 'no such number', I wonder why is that? I thought I already set the condition if the number is existed and set found to True? any explanation? I got new problem, it didn't deleted the number I put as input...any helps ?

Comment: This code seems fine. Are you catering for new-feeds from the new file? as readline() will return a line with a return carriage

Comment: `print`is your friend. Try `print(repr(n), repr(num))` before the `if` and see if they are different. Notice the `repr` which shows more information about the object than the more friendly `str`.

Comment: Both `n` and `num` are strings, not numbers.  `n` will have a newline at the end and `num` won't.  So they'll never be equal.

Comment: @FrankYellin right, so how can I delete any number that I want to delete and put it as input?

Comment: @tdelaney they are different, repr(n) return an empty string and repr(num) return a number but string type

Comment: @Glycerine the code did not work and did not delete the number I wanted, I am not sure what's new feeds means?

Comment: Are you sure `repr` didn't return a string. If you entered 3, it should be `'3'` (note the quotes). If `repr(n)` returned an  empty string it means you reached end of file. If that happened on the first call to `readline` it means that you have an empty file.

Comment: @tdelaney sorry the one I did I put it in the last line and outside the loop, this time, I noticed repr(n) get me 1\n.  and repr(num) get me 1. both are string with quotes

Comment: Can you try to parse the int: n= int(n) #or to a new var.
A test:

>>> s = "25\n"
>>> n = 25
>>> nc = int(s)
>>> if (s==nc): print("EQ!")
...
>>>
>>> if (n==nc): print("EQ - numbers")
...
EQ - numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is that `'123' != '123\n'`. That is, a string without a newline at the end is not the same as that string with a newline a the end.

You obtain `num` by having the user enter a string using `num = input('please enter a number ')`, which gets you a value like `'123'`, which will not include a newline character.

You obtain `n` by calling `f.readline()`, which gets you a value like `'123\n'`, because `.readline()` reads upto and including the newline character.

There's many ways to fix your problem, but since both values are supposed to be string representations of integer values and `int()` doesn't care about whitespace like a newline at the end, this may be the best fix:

```
if int(n) != int(num):
    # etc.
```

However you could achieve the same with:

```
num = int(input('please enter a number '))
# and
n = int(f.readline())
```

Which has the advantage of throwing an error when it occurs, instead of later when you compare values.

Finally, if you do need to compare strings, you can get rid of the newline in various ways, like:

```
n = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `readline` does not strip the line termination character `\n` but `input` does. The solution is to strip the lines being read of non-text characters on the right of the line.

```
f = open('num.txt','r')
temf = open('temp.txt','w')
n = f.readline()
num = input('please enter a number ')
found = False
while n != '':
    print(repr(n), repr(num))
    if n.rstrip() != num:
        temf.write(str(n))
    else:
        found = True
    n = f.readline()
f.close()
temf.close()

if found:
    print('found,and removed')
else:
    print('no such number')
```

Comment: Your solution is correct, but the explanation suggests `input()` "strips" the newline off of the input, while it really never has it - the newline is specific to files (and in fact differs between OSes) while the enter key is basically always the carriage return (CR, `\x0D`)

Comment: @Grismar - Not really. `\n` is the line termination symbol for C. The first TTY's sent `\r\n` (memorialized in modern protocols such as http) but that messed with the desire for a single character line terminator, so TTY drivers convert. Windows console puts a single CR in the console buffer. But EBCDIC terminals do (did?) 0x15. Its all sorted out to newline. Try `cat multilinefile.txt | python3 test.py` ... those are newlines in the pipe. Try `sys.stdin.buffer.readline()` ... again newline.